# Adding vectors present in two different RDDs scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two RDDs with this structure

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]
```

Here each row of RDD contains an index `Long` and a vector `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`. 
I want to add each component of the `Vector` into the corresponding component of other `Vector` present in a row of other RDD. Each vector of first RDD should be added to each vector of other RDD.

An example would look like this:

RDD1:

```
Array[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] = 
      Array((0,[0.1,0.2]),(1,[0.3,0.4]))
```

RDD2:

```
Array[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] = 
      Array((0,[0.3,0.8]),(1,[0.2,0.7]))
```

Result:

```
Array[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] = 
Array((0,[0.4,1.0]),(0,[0.3,0.9]),(1,[0.6,1.2]),(1,[0.5,1.1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the same situation using List instead of Array.

Here is my solution:

```
    val l1 = List((0,List(0.1,0.2)),(1,List(0.1,0.2)))
    val l2 = List((0,List(0.3,0.8)),(1,List(0.2,0.7)))
    var sms = (l1 zip l2).map{ case (m, a) => (m._1, (m._2, a._2).zipped.map(_+_))}
```

Let's experiment with Array :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of driver code you can do all this in transformation . This will be helpful if you have large rdds. This will perform less shuffling too.

```
val a:RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]= sc.parallelize(Array((0l,Vectors.dense(0.1,0.2)),(1l,Vectors.dense(0.3,0.4))))

val b:RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)]= sc.parallelize(Array((0l,Vectors.dense(0.3,0.8)),(1l,Vectors.dense(0.2,0.7))))

val ab= a join b

val result=ab.map(x => (x._1,Vectors.dense(x._2._1.apply(0)+x._2._2.apply(0),x._2._1.apply(1)+x._2._2.apply(1))))
```

Comment: The result is not correct, I want to add each vector in first RDD to each vector of other RDD, as mentioned in the example.

Comment: show me your progress.. we are not here to write code on behalf of you.. show your progress plus your problem where do you get stuck and then we will help you